# Virtualbox: switching USB phone capture between guest and host (Ubuntu and Mac)?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using Virtualbox with a Linux Ubuntu guest and MacOS host (MacBook Pro laptop). I am doing Android development, and for various reasons, I have to use an SDK on both Linux and MacOS. When I plug in my Android phone via USB to my MacBook Pro, the Virtualbox software automatically captures the phone correctly in the Linux host (using both 'developer' and 'USB mass storage' Android modes), thereby making the phone not visible to the MacOS host.

However, I cannot get Virtualbox to release the phone from the guest so that I can have the phone visible in the host. I have to quit the Virtualbox software completely. Anyone know what I can do to switch the phone's visibility back and forth between the host and the guest?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the devices menu of VirtualBox. There is also a small usb icon on the bottom right that gives you access to the same options.